# Efficient way to create a new list based of the differences in values in 2 dictionaries?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

I currently have 2 strings that are formatted as an XML that are later converted into dictionaries for comparison.

So, I have a 2 Dictionary<string, object>, dict1 and dict2, that I need to compare. I need to:

1. Add the key to a list of strings if the values of these two dictionaries do not match
2. Add the key of dict2 to the list if dict1 does not contain this key

Currently, I have a simple foreach loop

```
foreach (string propName in dict2.Keys)
{
    string oldDictValue;
    string newDicValue = dict1[propName].ToString();
    if (dict1.ContainsKey(propName))
    {
        oldDictValue = dict2[propName].ToString();
        if (oldDictValue != newDicValue)
            list.Add(propName);
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(propName);
    }

}
```

I would like to a faster solution to this problem if possible?

Comment: There's not going to be anything faster - execution-wise - than the loop you have. Did you have some other metric in mind?

Comment: You can use linq to make it look better

Comment: Comparing objects via `ToString()` looks a bit suspicious to me, TBH.

Comment: As for improving execution time you can try running it in parallel and adding results to `ConcurrentBag` instead of list.

Comment: The code you have won't work because it will throw a NullException if dict1 doesn't have the dict2 key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't claim that this is any faster, but it should be on par and it's less code:

```
List<string> list =
    dict2
        .Keys
        .Where(k => !(dict1.ContainsKey(k) && dict1[k].Equals(dict2[k])))
        .ToList();
```

I did do some testing with this:

```
List<string> list =
    dict2
        .Keys
        .AsParallel()
        .Where(k => !(dict1.ContainsKey(k) && dict1[k].Equals(dict2[k])))
        .ToList();
```

That produced a significantly faster run.

Here's how I produced my test data:

```
var dict1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(x => Random.Shared.Next(2000000)).Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.ToString(), x => (object)Random.Shared.Next(20));
var dict2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(x => Random.Shared.Next(2000000)).Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.ToString(), x => (object)Random.Shared.Next(20));
```

Comment: Could you share some metrics about the difference in performance? How much faster is the `.AsParallel()` version compared to the OP's version?

Comment: I was getting around 918ms versus 220ms. There abouts.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it faster by avoiding to get separately the `dict1[propName]` and the `dict2[propName]`. You could get the value along with the key, either by enumerating directly the [`KeyValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2)s stored in the dictionary, or by calling the [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue) method:

```
foreach (var (key, value2) in dict2)
{
    if (!dict1.TryGetValue(key, out var value1)
        || value1.ToString() != value2.ToString())
    {
        list.Add(key);
    }
}
```